# Trying to incorporate a C++ file in CubeIDE

Tags: c++, stm32, stm32cubeide

I am trying to use a C++ header file in my project but it is giving a syntax error. I have tried to convert the project to a C++ project but the error still persists. I don't know exactly and very much confused on how to use `extern C` command and `#ifdef`. My C++ header file goes like this:

```
#pragma once

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>
template <class NumberFormat, size_t DFT_Length>
class SlidingDFT
{
 private:
 ///////////////rest of the code goes here/////
```

Now if i include this file in my `Main.c` file and instantiate an object it gives an error: `syntax error`

Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanx in advance.

Comment: main.c is compiled with a C compiler. To create objects in main, you need to compile it with a C++ compiler. Rename it to main.cpp and see if it works.

Comment: Tried but this error: `make: *** No rule to make target '../Core/Src/main.c', needed by 'Core/Src/main.o'.  Stop.`

Comment: Also, please include the Makefile you are using by editing the question.

Comment: Somehow I am not able to format the makeFile in the post. But I can see Linker Specific errors in the last section: `fail-specified-linker-script-missing:
 @echo 'Error: Cannot find the specified linker script. Check the linker settings in the build configuration.'
 @exit 2

warn-no-linker-script-specified:
 @echo 'Warning: No linker script specified. Check the linker settings in the build configuration.'

.PHONY: all clean dependents fail-specified-linker-script-missing warn-no-linker-script-specified`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have C++ code (template class) in a header file that is being included in a C file.  The C compiler doesn't know how to deal with that.

You can and should wrap your C++ code like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
template <class NumberFormat, size_t DFT_Length>
class SlidingDFT
{
 private:
 ///////////////rest of the code goes here/////   
.
.
.
#endif
```

That will keep you C++ code from being seen by the C compiler.

The other issue you mentioned is extern "C" linkage for functions and when to use it.  When you have functions that need to be called from plain C code, they will need to have C linkage.  Here are some things to know.

- Functions defined in a .c module will have C linkage.
- Functions defined in a .cpp module by default will have C++ linkage and will not be able to be called (easily) by C code.
- You need to define any functions in a C++ module that you intend to call from C with C linkage.  There are required steps in both the .cpp and .h files.

C linkage in .cpp/.h files:

In the .cpp file, define your functions like this:

```
extern "C" void myfunc() 
{
   //code
}
```

Then in the .h file do this:

```
#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void myfunc();

#ifdef _cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Now your .h file can be included in both .c and .cpp modules AND the function myfunc() can be called in both as well.